# jQuery Validate plugin issue with another input outside of require_from_group

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

asking a new question in a different way because my last one was too similar to something that had already been answered.

I have a basic form with three fields; `fieldOne`, `fieldTwo` and `fieldThree`.

`fieldOne` and `fieldTwo` are dependent upon each other meaning at least one of them has to be provided.  `fieldThree` should always be provided.  So there will always be a minimum of two fields provided and a maximum of three.

This is the code I have so far.

```
var validator = $("#my_form").validate({
    groups: {
        datagroup: "fieldOne fieldTwo"
    },
    rules: {
        fieldOne: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.datagroup'],
            email: true,
            maxlength: {
                param: 40,
                depends: function (element) {
                    var valTwo = $('#fieldTwo').val();
                    var valThree = $('#fieldThree').val();
                    return ((!valTwo || (valTwo.length < 8) || (valTwo.length > 18) && !valThree));
                }
            }
        },
        fieldTwo: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.datagroup'],
            minlength: {
                param: 8,
                depends: function (element) {
                    var valOne = $('#fieldOne').val();
                    var valThree = $('#fieldThree').val();
                    return ((!valOne || (valOne.length > 40))&& !valThree);
                }
            }
        },
        fieldThree: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element){
                    var valOne = $('#fieldOne').val();
                    var valTwo = $('#fieldTwo').val();
                    return (!valOne || !valTwo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now it is pretty much at the point I need it to be at.  If I only provide `fieldThree` for instance, it asks me to input atleast one of the other two fields.  If I provide `fieldOne` only, it asks me to complete `fieldThree` etc.

There is only one thing I can't seem to get over though. I seem to be making it through the validation by providing `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo` only.  `fieldThree` is always required, so this should not get through.

How can I stop this from happening?  Realistically there are only three situations that should make it through:

```
fieldOne with fieldThree
fieldTwo with fieldThree
fieldOne and fieldTwo with fieldThree
```

This is what I am looking to achieve.

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you describe with the code you've provided. The form simply will not submit while field 3 is left empty: http://jsfiddle.net/y83uvj8u  ~ Please construct a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one problem here is that your `fieldThree` always returns `true` and don't get me wrong but i think the whole thing seems to be a bit over complicated, but maybe i am missing something. I don't know what your form actually looks like, but here is an example from what i think this is how you can approach what you are looking for.

```js
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});

var validator = $("#my_form").validate({
  rules: {
    fieldOne: {
      require_from_group: [1, '.datagroup'],
      email: true,
      maxlength: 40
    },
    fieldTwo: {
      require_from_group: [1, '.datagroup'],
      maxlength: 18,
      minlength: 8
    },
    fieldThree: {
      required: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<form id="my_form">
  <label for="fieldOne">Email: </label>
  <input type="email" class="datagroup" id="fieldOne" name="fieldOne">
  <br/>
  <label for="fieldTwo">Name: </label>
  <input type="text" class="datagroup" id="fieldTwo" name="fieldTwo">
  <br/>
  <label for="fieldThree">Accept: </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="fieldThree" name="fieldThree" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
```

And one thing to notice, be care full with `maxlength` on the `email` of `40`. As far as i know the maximum number of characters in an email is around 250, but not really sure about this <s>and i would consider this being part of the email filter</s>. Nope, just typed about a 1000 characters without triggering the validation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ***"but i think the whole thing seems to be a bit over complicated"*** ~ I totally agree with you there.  In both questions, the OP is complaining that the form is submitting even when field 3 is left empty.  However, I cannot reproduce that scenerio with the code he's provided:  http://jsfiddle.net/y83uvj8u/

Comment: @Sparky Strange, here is an example that does not work. http://codepen.io/DavidDomain/pen/qdxdZV

Comment: [Your codepen](http://codepen.io/DavidDomain/pen/qdxdZV) is working fine.  I cannot submit unless checkbox is checked.  You should check the links for the JS includes.  You are using links that auto-redirect to the CDN links.  Just use the CDN links directly.  They are posted on [the jQuery Validate homepage](http://jqueryvalidation.org).

Comment: Changed to CDN links, still not working. Not only the checkbox but minlength for fieldTwo not working either. What browser are you on? I am using Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 m. Might this be a browser problem?

Comment: I'm using Safari.  jQuery is supposed to normalize JavaScript across all browsers.  Regardless... it's working fine in jsFiddle so there is no problem with the code.  Although, I am not defending the OP's over-complication... he should simply use `required`.

Comment: Oh well, bye bye CodePen, hello jsFiddle. ;-) Should i delete my answer to not confuse other readers?

Comment: I think your answer is fine.  The OP needs to fix his question to show the code that reproduces the reported issue.  There are already lots of SO questions about how to use `require_from_group` and there is no good reason an unrelated field is ignoring the `required` rule.  Something is clearly missing here.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - The results David is getting is exactly the same as what I was getting, it can get pass without the third field.  I will try to simplyfy it and see if I can get it working.  Thanks